# MVVM - PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I am starting with MVVM.

My application uses this "pattern (PM pattern - let's not debate this here :)  )"and  works fine; The project is very simple and supposedly easy for beginners to get to grips with!! If only it was...  :)

There is one thing which is puzzling me, which may have nothing to do with MVVM per se; the PropertyChangedEventHandler.

I am stepping through my code, line by line and can see the call (code below) but I'm not sure why I am calling this handler or what it is doing!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace drMVVM.Model
{
    public class TextContent : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                if (text != value)
                {
                    text = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Text");
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I also have a similar layout of code for my viewmodel, but instead of setting the properties, I'm just creating an instance of the object and applying any additional logic.

Is the PropertyChangedEventArgs used to update just the properties of the model that something has changed? If so, why is it implemented in the model class and not just the ModelView? Is it because it can instinctively know whether to just listen for a change or to provide details a notification that a change occurs? If it's a notification (I assume so hence the name of the interface) then what am I notifying in my Model class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is required whenever you want to notify someone about changes of your properties. So if your ViewModel needs to notify the view about changes so the view updates its data binding, then you ViewModel needs to implement it and raise the event with every change of the properties.

Similar, if your model has properties that can change and you want to be notified about, then implement it in your model as well.

It’s not really *necessary* for something, unless there are automated implications for it; one being the data binding in WPF which needs a hint so it knows that it has to update.

Comment: Ahhhh... so, when my UI changes (which is bound to the VM, the VM notifies the model. The model updates and then re-notifies the VM which can then notify the View? Does that sound right? (VM = view model)

Comment: No, it goes from `INotifyPropertyChanged` to whatever bound to it. When the UI changes, it directly updates the values it bound to. But when the data changes, the event notifies the UI to update its displayed values. Similar when the VM is bound to the model, and the model updates its values, it notifies the VM.

Comment: hmmm... Now I'm back to square one again! :) My UI is bound to an object in the VM. The VM creates an instance of my model. Both VM and Model use the interface INotifyProperyChanged. So, when the UI changes it actually updates the Model (via the VM - which has created the object instance). This then triggers (raises the event) the PropertyChanged event, which updates the VM which then triggers it's PropertyChanged event which then in turn updates the UI (View)?

Comment: In that case, yes, although the model object within your VM does not automatically raise the event from the VM’s property, so that probably does not happen. But yeah, usually, for data binding, the event is only needed to update the bindings on the view side, as changes on the view directly modify the bindings and as such the underlying objects.